# How do I get all the urls of a video flv pieces only with Python?

Tags: python

The url for ordinary people to watch the video is: http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XNjM5NDU1OTUy.html

This video is split into 14 flv pieces, 5 of which are advertising flvs.

If I open the Developer Tools of IE11 and keep capturing the network flow during the whole process of watching the video (It must be the whole process, or the server doesn't send all of the video flv urls to IE11), the flv urls will be captured by IE11 and then I can copy the data of the flv urls which the below picture displays in a red line box:
[image]
Then I can change the data into a list of url-strings and use Python to download them.

But this is really trouble.

I have tried to match the source code of http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XNjM5NDU1OTUy.html with the flv urls, but no results. So I guess there must be a function or a javascript or something else in the code to tell the server to send all the flv urls. Am I right?

So,

1.How to get all the urls of a video flv pieces only with Python?

2.What should I learn to solve this kind of problem.

After all, using Developer Tools of IE11, waiting for the whole process of the video (nearly one hour), copying the related data to a txt file and finally using Python to parse the txt file are really something trouble.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could get some insights from [Youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/). It is a set of python scripts created to "*download Youtube videos and a few more sites"*. Go to their [Download](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html) section and get the [full source](https://yt-dl.org/downloads/2013.12.04/youtube-dl-2013.12.04.tar.gz) tarball. I think that could be useful in some way, at least to give you some directions on how to deal with flv pieces.

Comment: OH this is really a powerful downloader. thank you very much.